# IP Address showing instead of Domain name on my Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, ip-address, domain-name

I am having an issue where I have a Domain name from Go Daddy, and I am hosting a WP site on Amazon Web Services EC2.   I have already changed the A record to so the site pulls up anytime i go to www.bemoremarketing.com.  Everything works fine until I hit the home bottom on the website.   At that point the IP comes up in in the address bar.   Any pages i access after that will have the IPaddress/page

From what I have gathered, I may need to change something in the wp-config.php, but I am unable to find where this is.    Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the Site URL.

You can do this through the Wordpress Settings at Settings > General > Wordpress Address/Site Address, or in the wp-config.php file

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress' );
```

For more details see https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL.

Comment: Hello.   Wordpress Address/Site Address are greyed out so I need to access the wp-config.php file.   I was going to try to use FileZilla to access the server and download the file, when the instance was set up on AWS EC2 it was done without generating a Key Pair so now I cannot access the back end of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings of wordpress. Then, change the URL as given below.
[image: settings page]

Comment: I did this and now I get 502 errors when I try to access my site but I can reach my wordpress dashboard. Any knowledge on this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is still of interest but make sure you have all your pages linking to the actual www.yoursite.com

Also, make sure that your HOME link on the menu links to the www.yoursite.com instead of IP.

Changes made in the WP Settings > General are also needed.

Comment: To a certain degree, this rather reads like some generic comments, not like a real answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the same issue. My domain name is purchased from GoDaddy too. I use a raspberry pi and wordpress to build a website.

For GoDaddy.com, following this [explain](https://vn.godaddy.com/help/whats-the-difference-between-domain-forwarding-and-masking-32147),

- Use **Forwarding with masking** in your DNS management.
- After changing wait for a while.
- Go to your website by searching your domain name and it won't change to IP address on the address bar.

I didn't modify WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)